# Bottom tabs in the Android 4 or later as in iPad application

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, android-tabhost, android-tabs

I am developing an android application which is the iPhone version for Android devices and this iPhone application has the bottom tabs.

These types of tabs are present in the many iPhone applications.

For example:

[image]

I want to know the best way to implement these types of tabs in the bottom in android.

I am developing this application for the android 4.0 or later where tab activity does not work.

**My Problems:**

1) As Android latest versions do not support to the tab activity, then what will be the solution? (Deprecated things are not good way to use)

Answer (score 3):

Follow Android design guidelines [Pure Android](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/pure-android.html)